# How to get back the vanilla bookmarks folder color in Firefox 57?

Tags: windows, firefox, firefox-57

I am not a fan of the bookmarks folder colors in Firefox 57 default theme:

[image]

In prior version the folders were colored in vanilla color:

[image]

Is there anyway to get that color back in Firefox 57?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/73l3qn/how_to_change_the_icon_color_of_bookmarks_folders/):

> You can load custom images by adding this to your userchrome:
>
> .bookmark-item[container] { list-style-image: url( /* url goes here */
>   ); }
>
> Easiest way of using custom images is using a base64 encode string as
>   the url. Here's a monochrome chrome icon as an example:
>   https://pastebin.com/mF3EpcFu
>
> You can use something like www.base64-image.de to convert your own
>   files into base64.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work. Maybe I've missed some details that could be explained?

Answer (score 2):

Another way, also based on `userChrome.css`:

```css
/* Colored folders for bookmark sidebar, toolbar, menu button */
  /* Standard folder */
#bookmarks-view treechildren::-moz-tree-image(container),
#PlacesToolbarItems toolbarbutton[container="true"] .toolbarbutton-icon,
#PlacesToolbarItems menu[container="true"] .menu-iconic-left,
#BMB_bookmarksPopup menu[container="true"] .menu-iconic-icon {
  fill: #e8bb00 !important; /* slightly muted gold */
}
  /* Live Bookmark (RSS Feed) */
#bookmarks-view treechildren::-moz-tree-image(container, livemark),
#PlacesToolbarItems toolbarbutton[container="true"][livemark="true"] .toolbarbutton-icon,
#PlacesToolbarItems menu[container="true"][livemark="true"] .menu-iconic-left,
#BMB_bookmarksPopup menu[container="true"][livemark="true"] .menu-iconic-icon {
  fill: orange !important;
}
  /* Smart bookmark folder */
#bookmarks-view treechildren::-moz-tree-image(container, query),
#PlacesToolbarItems toolbarbutton[container="true"][query="true"] .toolbarbutton-icon,
#PlacesToolbarItems menu[container="true"][query="true"] .menu-iconic-left,
#BMB_bookmarksPopup menu[container="true"][query="true"] .menu-iconic-icon {
  fill: #69c !important; /* similar to blue smart folder color */
}
  /* These "containers" are SVG in the sidebar, not yet on the menu */
#bookmarks-view treechildren::-moz-tree-image(container, OrganizerQuery_BookmarksMenu) {
  fill: olive !important;
}
#bookmarks-view treechildren::-moz-tree-image(container, OrganizerQuery_BookmarksToolbar) {
  fill: olive !important;
}
#bookmarks-view treechildren::-moz-tree-image(container, OrganizerQuery_UnfiledBookmarks) {
  fill: olive !important;
}
```

This solution comes from [here](https://www.userchrome.org/what-is-userchrome-css.html#colorbookmarkfolder).

More generally, [userchrome.org](https://www.userchrome.org) seems to be a valuable source of information (and recipes) about `userChrome.css`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download [this archive](https://www.userchrome.org/samples/Fx56_bookmark_buttons.zip) and extract all contents into firefox's chrome folder (`%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<your-profile>\chrome` (create if it doesnt exist))
2. If you don't have a `userChrome.css` file, rename `userChrome-STARTER.css` to `userChrome.css`. If you do, copy the line from `userChrome-STARTER.css` to the top of your `userChrome.css` file.
3. Restart firefox, you will now have the old folders back.

[Source](https://www.userchrome.org/what-is-userchrome-css.html#colorbookmarkfolder)

Answer (score 1):

1. I took the 200px  version of https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Icons8_flat_folder.svg:

   [image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a1/Icons8_flat_folder.svg/200px-Icons8_flat_folder.svg.png]
2. Changed the size to 50px and added a gradient:

   [image]
3. Converted it to Base64 at https://www.base64-image.de/.
4. Added this to `<FF profile folder>/chrome/userChrome.css`:

   ```
   /* From: https://superuser.com/questions/1268367/how-to-get-back-the-vanilla-bookmarks-folder-color-in-firefox-57/1348373#1348373 */

   .bookmark-item[container]
       {
       list-style-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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') !important;
       }
   ```
5. Restarted FF.
6. Enjoyed!